# Array function in Excel that returns any date from column A where the row meets all three criteria in column G

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

[excel question for array function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HBXK.jpg)Need an array function in cell I3 that returns any date from column A where the row meets all three criteria in column G (Start Date, End Date, and Minimum Revenue)

I know INDEX would yield the exact row but in this case I'm not able to understand how to access proper row no

```
{=INDEX(A3:A14,IF((A3:A14>=G2)*(A3:A14<=G3)*(C3:C14>=G4),ROW(A3:A14)))}
```

Comment: are you asking the internet to do some sort of assignment for you?

Comment: @Lambik I have no issue helping out with assignments providing the student learns from the answer I provide - Some people just need that extra insight

Comment: It's not an assignment. I am trying to look for an alternative solution which is understandable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there - you just need to offset the row number to the 1 based index then make use of `SMALL()` to nab the smallest row in the array:

`{=INDEX(A3:A14,SMALL(IF((A3:A14>=G2)*(A3:A14<=G3)*(C3:C14>=G4),ROW(A3:A14)-ROW(A3)+1),1))}`

**Edit - As per OP request**

`SMALL([array/range],[k])` is a simple function that returns the nth (argument k) smallest result from the array / range.

As the current `IF()` array will produce a resulting array of either FALSE or the row number (something like `{FALSE;2;FALSE;4;FALSE;FALSE;7}` etc. without the SMALL - we'll only ever get the first result returned so if your criteria doesn't match the first row you'll instead get an error.

Using `SMALL([IF-Array],1)` we are able to pull down the first smallest result from that array which equates to the first row where all criteria are met.

You can expand on this formula to use `ROW(1:1)` as the `[k]` argument which will allow you to drag the formula down to get each match thereafter

Comment: can you please explain why you are using `SMALL()` and how is it helping to achieve our result?

Comment: thank you so much.. for your clear explanation, it helped me a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is VBA. Let us assume that all data appears in Sheet 1. Import the below code on Sheet 1 change event.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LastrowA As Long, LastrowI As Long, i As Long
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Dim MinimunRevenue As Double

    'Check if Criteria range affected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1:G3")) Is Nothing Then

        'Check if all criteria are imported
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("G1").Value) = True And Not IsEmpty(Range("G2").Value) = True And Not IsEmpty(Range("G3").Value) = True Then

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                'Get Criteria Values
                StartDate = .Range("G1").Value
                EndDate = .Range("G2").Value
                MinimunRevenue = .Range("G3").Value

                'Loop all lines
                For i = 2 To LastrowA

                    'Chek if contitions meet
                    If (.Range("A" & i).Value >= StartDate And .Range("A" & i).Value <= EndDate) _
                        And .Range("C" & i).Value >= MinimunRevenue Then
                            'If conditions meet import lines in the new table
                            Application.EnableEvents = False
                                LastrowI = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
                                .Range("I" & LastrowI + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                                .Range("J" & LastrowI + 1).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
                                .Range("K" & LastrowI + 1).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                                .Range("L" & LastrowI + 1).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
                            Application.EnableEvents = True
                    End If

                Next i

            End With

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]